# Jetty vs. Apache Tomcat for small Java Project

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, embedded-jetty

After looking around for info on both technologies, I'm still undecided what would be the best option for a small Java project. Stability and ease of implementation is what I'm looking for, rather than performance.

What's the best choice here?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In other words, this question is too subjective to fit in here :)

Comment: The description is too little to offer any useful insight, I would also suggest you to take a look at spring boot.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :) I should rephrase the question then: in your experience, is there any reason not to use Jetty instead of Tomcat, since the former seems to be the more lightweight and perfomance is not an issue in this specific case?

Comment: @J.Silva sadly, these kinds of questions do not result in quality answers, and are discouraged.  It would be best if you try both, learn, and ask targeted questions about specific experiences or behaviors you are having.